# Find and exclude html-tags as whole words in negative lookbehind with regex

Tags: html, regex, negative-lookbehind

I basically try to find all paragraphs (in javascript/jquery) in a text, that are not yet wrapped in a set of defined html-tags:

```
p|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|blockquote|img|table|iframe
```

My current regex (https://regex101.com/r/O4i2hP/1) already matches paragraphs and excludes the defined tags

(.+?(?<![</(p|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|blockquote|img|table|iframe)>]$))(\n|$)+/gm

but I just don't get, how to just match whole tags only.

The problem is:

> (p|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|blockquote|img|table|iframe)> matches a single
> character in the list (p|h123456blockquteimgafr)> (case sensitive)

Thus, as you can see from the example, code that is wrapped in tags such as `<strong>TEXT</strong>` is also excluded.

I tried different things such as word boundaries `\bword\b`, but didn't get it working. I hope you can help. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://regex101.com/r/Wqhm2F/1) will do it.

^(?!<(p|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|blockquote|img|table|iframe)+?>.*</\1>).*$

Comment: Thank you. This is even more accurate than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I now found a working approach. The tags should be wrapped in groups rather than in character classes. The following works for me:

```
(.+?(?<!(<\/)(p|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|blockquote|img|table|iframe)(>)$))(\n|$)+/gm
```

see also: https://regex101.com/r/DC5msM/1